# Smoothly fade color image to grayscale based on input value between 0-1 for RGB Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, led

I am writing some code to display a camera input to a 32*32 LED array.

My code to get the image and display it looks like this:

```
def start_cam(x,y):
    # Start the webcam
    webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    # Set frame rate to 45 frames per second
    frame_rate = 45

    # Loop 45 times per second
    while True:
        # Capture a frame from the webcam
        ret, frame = webcam.read()

        # Resize the frame to 16x16
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (x, y))
        frame = sp_noise(frame,0.85)

        # Get input orientation
        orientation = 0
        # Rotate the frame by 90 degrees based on user input
        if orientation == 1:
            frame = np.rot90(frame)
        elif orientation == 2:
            frame = np.rot90(frame, 2)
        elif orientation == 3:
            frame = np.rot90(frame, 3)

        # Initialize empty list to store RGB values
        rgb_list = []

        # Loop through each pixel in the frame
        for i in range(x):
            for j in range(y):
                # Get RGB values of each pixel
                r, g, b = frame[i, j]
                # Append RGB values to list
                rgb_list = rgb_list + [b, g, r]

        # Print the list of RGB values
        #print(rgb_list)
        rgb_out = []
        for i in rgb_list:
            rgb_out.append(gamma[i]//2)
        rgb_out = sp_noise(rgb_out,0.2)
        temp_send(rgb_out, x,y)
```

I have a function already made called sp.noise that adds salt and pepper static to the image based on a value between 0-1. I would like to make a second image processing function that would have the image go from being fully colored at a value of 0, to fully gray at a value of 1.

How could I go about making a smooth gray-scale function for my RGB value NP array?

I wrote a function that simply computes both gray and color, and averages them weighing them based on the input value, but that is incredibly inefficient. And reduces my FPS to unusable levels.

Answer (score 2):

To "make an image fully gray" is to desaturate an image; so removing the colors while retaining the hue and brightness of the pixels. You can:

1. First, convert your RGB image into HSL space. This will convert your `(red, green, blue)` pixel triplets into `(hue, saturation, lightness)` triplets, where "how much color a pixel has" is contained within the single value `saturation`.

- For OpenCV you can use something like `output = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)` or with `cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV` depending on your input color
- [Simple example from GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-cvtcolor-method/)
- [OpenCV example](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html)

2. Then you can write a simple desaturation function. For example, a function to multiply the `saturation` of each pixel by your value of range [0,1]. This will make the image "fully gray" at 0, and "fully color" at 1.
3. (Optional) You can then convert the image back to RGB if necessary with the same function, but different flag: `output = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)`

Comment: So I tried to do this:

```
        #apply desaturation effect
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
        frame[:,1,:] = frame[:,1,:] * 0
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)

```
however, the image doesn't get gray at all?

Comment: @Androo Your indexing is incorrect - it should be `frame[:,:,1]` and not `frame[:,1,:]` for the saturation channel.